# Strange ctypes behaviour on python callable wrapping c callable with c_char_p argtype

Tags: python-3.x, string, byte, ctypes, mutable

I'm observing a strange ctypes related behaviour in the following test program:

```
import ctypes as ct

def _pyfunc(a_c_string):
    print(type(a_c_string))
    a_c_string.value = b"87654321"
    return -123

my_str_buf = ct.create_string_buffer(b"test1234")
print(type(my_str_buf))

my_str_buf[3] = b'*'
print(my_str_buf.value)

my_str_buf.value = b"4321test"
print(my_str_buf.value)

signature = ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p)
pyfunc = signature(_pyfunc)
pyfunc(my_str_buf)
print(my_str_buf.value)
```

The example wraps a python c callable in a python function via the ctypes api.
The goal is to pass the python function a pointer to a c string let it modify it's contents (providing a fake value) and then return to the caller.

I started by the creation of a mutable string buffer via the ctypes function `create_string_buffer`.
As can be seen from the example, the string buffer is indeed mutable.

After that i create a c function prototype using `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p)` and then instantiate that prototype with my python function which should be called using the same signature. Finally i call the python function with my mutable string buffer.

What irritates me is that the argument passed to that function shape shifts from type of  `<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_9'>` to `<class 'bytes'>` when the function is called. Unfortunately, the original mutable datatype turned into a completely useless non mutable bytes object.

Is this a ctypes bug? Python Version is 3.6.6.

Here is the output:

```
<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_9'>
b'tes*1234'
b'4321test'
<class 'bytes'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 234, in 'calling callback function'
  File "C:/Users/andree/source/Python_Tests/ctypes_cchar_prototype.py", line 5, in _pyfunc
    a_c_string.value = b"87654321"
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'value'
b'4321test'
```

Expected output:

```
<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_9'>
b'tes*1234'
b'4321test'
<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_9'>
b'87654321'
```

Comment: What if you change your argument type to `ct.c_char * 9`? So `signature = ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.c_char * 9)`.

Comment: I noticed that it still doesn't reflect the exact behavior you want. It's passing `my_str_buf` by value. If you want to mutate `my_str_buf` within the function you can pass it by reference like `pyfunc(ct.byref(my_str_buf))`. This will require you to change the argument type to a pointer to a char array. `signature = ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char * 9))` and within the function modify the contents of that pointer. `a_c_string.contents.value = b"87654321"` All in all, that should give you the behavior you want.

Comment: That works, too. As a side effect it requires me to pass exact width strings. This may be an advantage or not. In my case, this is just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctypes.c_char_p` is automatically converted to Python `bytes`.  If you don't want the behavior, use either:

- `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))`
- `class PCHAR(ctypes.c_char_p): pass` (derivations suppress the behavior)

Note that an `LP_c_char` doesn't have a `.value` property, so I had to directly dereference the pointer to affect change in the value.

Also, be careful not to exceed the length of the mutable buffer passed in.  I added `length` as an additional parameter.

Example:

```py
import ctypes as ct

@ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char), ct.c_size_t)
def pyfunc(a_c_string,length):
    new_data = b'87654321\x00' # ensure new null termination is present.
    if len(new_data) > length: # ensure new data doesn't exceed buffer length
        return 0 # fail
    for i,c in enumerate(new_data):
        a_c_string[i] = c
    return 1 # pass

my_str_buf = ct.create_string_buffer(10)
result = pyfunc(my_str_buf,len(my_str_buf))
print(result,my_str_buf.value)

my_str_buf = ct.create_string_buffer(8)
result = pyfunc(my_str_buf,len(my_str_buf))
print(result,my_str_buf.value)
```

```
1 b'87654321'
0 b''
```

Comment: This helped me. Strange that it makes a difference if i use `ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char), ct.c_size_t)` vs. `ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p, ct.c_size_t)`. Thought `ct.c_char_p`beeing just an alias for `ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)`.

Comment: @pqans `c_char_p` has special handling to convert to a Python bytes object.  It's not only an alias.

Comment: That was the source of my misunderstanding. Good to know.

Comment: @pqnas `c_void_p` has similar special handling.  It converts to Python `None` or Python `int`.

Comment: "Note that an LP_c_char doesn't have a .value property, so I had to directly [...]" -> Need to use `.contents.value`, instead.

Comment: @pqans Yes, or the much shorter [] syntax I actually used. The point was can’t assign a string as the OP tried.